# service account - best practise

Tags: google-cloud-iam

some questions about service accounts and best practises on GCP.

1) I'm able to create a "brand new" service account. How can I ensure that this new service account doesn't have any kind of privileges bound to it? I'm asking this because for a project I need to create multiple service accounts with only one permission: write access to a *single* Google Storage bucket. Nothing more. How can I ensure that this is the only granted permission and nothing else ?

2) Should I create a new Google Cloud Project for every customer I have, in example, one project for each website that I'll host to GCP or a single company project (in this case, my company) would be enough to hold all Compute Instances, Storage buckets and so on, needed by my customers ?
Managing hundreds of project would be overkill, if possible, i prefere to avoid this, without impacting secutiry.

Thank you.

Comment: Any help about this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can only constrain service account permissions to enabled services that implement IAM (the Google Cloud Platform services including Cloud Storage). For services that don't implement IAM, the only way to limit a service account's auth is through OAuth scopes.
2. Projects appear provide a more robust security perimeter for you to separate your tenant customers. Additionally, you get enforced separation of billing, logging, auditing etc. It's debatable whether managing per customer projects (each owning a bucket and related service accounts) has different security than a multi-customer project (with many buckets and service accounts) since service accounts may be easily extended across projects. I recommend whichever path you choose, you ensure control is effected programmatically to minimize human error of granting one customer's account(s) to another customer's bucket(s).

HTH!